# Android Retrofit: URL with braces ' { } ' causing errors

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am trying to fetch data from the following api:

```
https://site/api/requestpost/gethttp?dbName=ERP&PN=Mobile_CustomerList_P&JSONUser={"mb_code":"11111","pwd":"2222","id":"0000"}&JSONData={}
```

My code:

```
@GET(baseUrl+"gethttp?dbName=ERP&PN=Mobile_CustomerList_P&JSONUser={"+ "\"mb_code\":\"{key}\",\"pwd\":\"sj12\",\"id\":\"0000\"}&JSONData={{data}}")
            Call<ResponseBody> downloadData(@Path(value = "key") String code, @Path("data")String data);
```

where

```
baseURL = "https://site/api/requestpost/";
key = "1111";
data = "";
```

With this code I am getting an error which says

```
...{{data}}"must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query
```

Since this api has '{ }' in it, it's getting very hard to put it in retrofit.

I guess this error is because of the braces but they are a part of the api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retrofit expects you to build your service interface something like this:

```
@GET(baseUrl+"gethttp")
Call<ResponseBody> downloadData(
    @Query("dbName") String dbName,
    @Query("PN") String pn,
    @Query("JSONUser") String jsonUser,
    @Query("JSONData") String jsonData
);
```

Comment: hey lars.. it worked...but how did retrofit figure out the '?' after gethttp

Comment: The path (`/api/requestpost/gethttp`) and the query string (`dbName=ERP&PN=Mobile_CustomerList_P&JSONUser={"mb_code":"11111","pwd":"2222","id":"0000"}&JSONData={}`) are always delimited by a `?`. This is defined here (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1738#section-3.3) and here (https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html). So when retrofit builds the query parameters for the url it knows it has to add a `?` before.